# Why is everything involving machine learning called AI lately?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, artificial-intelligence

Why is everyone calling AI something that is nothing more than a trivial predictive algorithm or something that it was simply called machine learning not more than one year ago?

Comment: It sounds fancier. You say statistics, you think of numeric tables. You say machine learning, you think of recommendation systems. You say AI, you think of robots who make your coffee and smile.

Comment: If you call something "logistic regression" or an "additive model" or a "linear discriminant analysis" or "k-means" it sounds like something you'd pay a newly minted statistician a couple of thousand dollars for. The people who want to call that AI don't want to get out of bed for a mere couple of thousand. Calling it AI makes it sound like it's worth more.

Comment: As it has been said in the 2 previous comments, it's a pure "marketing" strategy: it sounds cooler, never mind a significant bunch of what is being called AI is just plain old, classical statistics IMHO. By the way, the same goes with "algorithm": where you used to hear "model", "theory", etc. now you hear much more often "algorithm" in my personal experience, even if what the person is describing is NOT an algorithm but a model.

Comment: @Glen_b This question is off-topic/irrelevant, yet gets a double standard because you have something to say about it.

Comment: @cagdas 1. If you think it's off topic, flag it (or vote to close if you have privilege to do that); you're as responsible for what's seen as off topic as I am. Mods are meant to be "exception handlers" and this is not something that ordinary users with sufficient privilege couldn't figure out whether or not to close. 2. Your characterization of my motives is misplaced. A much simpler explanation -- that I simply didn't consider whether it was off topic -- is the correct one. A careful examination of my actions would reveal that I often edit or comment on posts that ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... I later (when in moderating mode) close. I've even answered questions that I have later closed as off topic (as have some other mods now and then). Note that if you want to take up the issue of moderator actions, the correct place would be a post on meta -- link to this thread and cast your aspersions on my motives/character there. This looks like it has only one close vote now, but if it's still open at the time, I'll try to review it on my next pass of looking for things to close.

Comment: Here's an official quote about site moderators and their role: "*Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community.

The most common moderator task is to follow up on flagged posts. [...] anyone with 15 reputation can use. [...]
If you see anything in the system that is evil, weird, or in any way exceptional and deserving of moderator attention for any reason…flag it!*" ... so the actual StackExchange position about moderator responsibilities is placed first into the hands of users with 15+ reputation

Comment: @Glen_b. Voted. From now on you will get utmost scrutiny from me. I will be watching your every step and will criticize any double standard to maximum extent. Thanks.

Comment: Again, please take it to meta where a proper discussion of the issues can take place..

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc unless obvious cases, it is often hard to draw a clear-cut line between on-topic and off-topic questions. Often the decisions *are* somehow arbitrary. I'm not talking only about mods in here, but also about community votes. There is lots of threads where I disagreed with either closing of leaving open decisions. Hopefully in most cases the actions can be reverted. Check this recent thread for related discussion: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/whats-the-point-of-putting-unclear-questions-on-hold

Answer (score 2):

Artificial intelligence field has different approaches and branches, such as [machine learning](https://www.britannica.com/technology/machine-learning) (ML). It's not wrong to call ML techniques AI. Also, ML had a lot of new developments, it was being rapidly adopted recently. That's why it's in the conversation a lot. It may appear as if people started calling it AI only lately. I don't think it's the case, so I wouldn't be cynical about this. As long as you remember that ML is not the whole AI, it's Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that AI is just a "fancy" name for ML used for marketing, as some of the comments seem to say.

The "immediate" aims of AI is to computationally solve problems that humans (or some other biological intelligent agent) can solve naturally in short time (something like a few hundred milliseconds). The examples include, face recognition, natural language understanding etc.

I think Andrew Ng says it somewhere in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1ka6a13S9I).

Also see [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2016/12/06/what-is-the-difference-between-artificial-intelligence-and-machine-learning/#44b256ea2742) that tries to clarify the difference.